# Why won't this xhtml validate? W3C validator

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

Not sure why it won't validate it's pretty simple... any ideas?

http://pastebin.com/uMPUzH09

Comment: `Line 19, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified` http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: it keeps adding its own doctype but its exactly the same as the one i already have...

Comment: It? Who, what, where, who? Details, please. In the online version I linked to, there is a setting under Options to add a DOCTYPE only if one is not detected. I suppose that addresses the problem you've alluded to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is pretty verbose:

```
Line 19, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
</body>

You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
```

You're missing a closing `</div>` tag:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="top_gray"></div>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="left_container"></div>
    <div id="center_container"></div>
    <div id="right_container"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
  ^^^^^^ You forgot me
</div>
```

Comment: Questions like these could very well drive a man to read Nietzsche.

Comment: If only there were a reason to try. What is life but a mime with shingles sharing the misery of one hand clapping? It is nothing, we are *nothing*, I sit in endless despair at your suggestion.

Comment: The only obscure thing in the validator’s message is “but OMITTAG NO was specified”, and it is caused by the SGML heritage. SGML allows end tags to be omitted according to certain rules, XML doesn’t.

Comment: That's really deep bro. *Really* deep.

Comment: Deep dodo. I can't believe this question hasn't been vote closed.

Comment: Here's some more dodo for your late night pleasure. *[Hoisted! A Comment in One Act](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975465/what-is-the-difference-between-the-below-syntaxes#comment14333836_10975547)*

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver it didn't alert me to the non closed div.

Answer (score 2):

`<div id="header">` is unclosed

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="main_container">` is not closed.

Indent your code well in a decent editor and you should be able to find these things easily.

W3C's validator points it out pretty clearly.

Comment: also seems to have a problem with the doctype.