# what is the difference between the below syntaxes?

Tags: javascript

```
1. $(function () {
       function foo() { return true; }
       log(bar());                        // getting error
       var bar = function() { return true; };   
  });

2. $(function () {
       function foo() { return true; }
       var bar = function() { return true; };
       log(bar());                        // Working   
  });
```

my confusion here is what is the difference between the below two declarations and which one is useful?

```
var bar = function() { return true; };

function bar(){ return true; };
```

Comment: You're calling `bar()` in the first example before it's been made available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The:

```
function bar(){ return true; };
```

is `function declaration` which is hoisted to top by the interpreter, you can call from **any place**, while:

```
var bar = function() { return true; };
```

is `function expression` you can call only ***after*** it is defined. It won't be available before or up in the code just like you were doing:

```
log(bar());                        // getting error
var bar = function() { return true; };
```

Getting error because on first line `bar` isn't available yet. To solve that, use `function declaration` instead if you want.

---

To learn more about the difference between `function declaration` and `function expression`, I highly recommend you to read this great article by [Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com):

- **[Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)**

Comment: *At the gates of the anonymously named function, the man in black stood back a step and thrust his foo bar petard into the fray. BUT HE WAS TOO EARLY! And the function, nameless yet, hoisted his request in cruel, cruel mockery.*

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Hehe that's a nice take at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sarfraz got a great explanation already. I just want to add more, the first function,

```
var bar = function(){ return true; };
```

is much more flexible, you can add some more properties, or methods after it is declared:

```
bar.anotherMethod = function() { alert("This is another method"); }
bar.anotherProperty = 'some value';
```

While `function bar(){ return true; }` cannot do it that way.
`

Comment: Both can do it eg both can have properties :)

Comment: oh! really? So I can call `bar.anyMethode = function() {...}` for `function bar(){ return true; }`?

Comment: If you apply the `anyMethode ` property to `function bar(){ return true; }`.